# Switch Toggling Event Using MVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms

I realized recently that a switch doesn't have a command. And i need to bind the toggling event to my view model. How do i go about it?

I tried to bind the command to Toggled event but the code is running into error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EventToCommandBehavior` to convert the event to command

> create the `EventToCommandBehavior` class

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xxx
{
    public class BehaviorBase<T> : Behavior<T> where T : BindableObject
    {
        public T AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(T bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
            AssociatedObject = bindable;

            if (bindable.BindingContext != null)
            {
                BindingContext = bindable.BindingContext;
            }

            bindable.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(T bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
            bindable.BindingContextChanged -= OnBindingContextChanged;
            AssociatedObject = null;
        }

        void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnBindingContextChanged();
        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            BindingContext = AssociatedObject.BindingContext;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xxx
{
    public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<View>
    {
        Delegate eventHandler;

        public static readonly BindableProperty EventNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create("EventName", typeof(string), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null, propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged);
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);
        public static readonly BindableProperty InputConverterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Converter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);

        public string EventName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(EventNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EventNameProperty, value); }
        }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public object CommandParameter
        {
            get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
        }

        public IValueConverter Converter
        {
            get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(InputConverterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InputConverterProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(View bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
            RegisterEvent(EventName);
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(View bindable)
        {
            DeregisterEvent(EventName);
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        }

        void RegisterEvent(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                return;
            }

            EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);
            if (eventInfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't register the '{0}' event.", EventName));
            }
            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(EventToCommandBehavior).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("OnEvent");
            eventHandler = methodInfo.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this);
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
        }

        void DeregisterEvent(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (eventHandler == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);
            if (eventInfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't de-register the '{0}' event.", EventName));
            }
            eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
            eventHandler = null;
        }

        void OnEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)
        {
            if (Command == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            object resolvedParameter;
            if (CommandParameter != null)
            {
                resolvedParameter = CommandParameter;
            }
            else if (Converter != null)
            {
                resolvedParameter = Converter.Convert(eventArgs, typeof(object), null, null);
            }
            else
            {
                resolvedParameter = eventArgs;
            }

            if (Command.CanExecute(resolvedParameter))
            {
                Command.Execute(resolvedParameter);
            }
        }

        static void OnEventNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var behavior = (EventToCommandBehavior)bindable;
            if (behavior.AssociatedObject == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            string oldEventName = (string)oldValue;
            string newEventName = (string)newValue;

            behavior.DeregisterEvent(oldEventName);
            behavior.RegisterEvent(newEventName);
        }
    }
}
```

> in your xaml

```
<Switch >
   <Switch.Behaviors>
      <local:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Toggled"  Command="{Binding ToggledCommand}"/>
   </Switch.Behaviors>
</Switch>
```

> And in your ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{   
  public ICommand ToggledCommand { get; private set; }

  public MyViewModel()
  {
     ToggledCommand = new Command(() => {

       // do some thing you want

      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bind a `bool` property on my viewmodel to the `IsToggled` property on the switch, then handle when this changes in the viewmodel.